# How can I add a subtype to this generic Collection?

Tags: java, generics, object

I want to have a collection of subclass objects but with my generic type implementation as it is now gives an error at `allItems.add(item);` because `allItems` does not hold `Item` types. So how can I change the below code not give an error?

```
public class ItemManager {
    public static Collection<? extends Item> allItems;
    ...
    public static boolean addItem(Item item){
        return allItems.add(item);
    }
}
```

A new item might be added as:

```
itemManager.add(new Bomb());
```

Is there a way to change `addItem` to:

```
public static boolean addItem([all subclasses of Item] item) { ... }
```

or maybe change `allItems` so it can accept receiving an `Item` and a subclass of `Item`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The collection should be declared as `Collection<Item>`.

`Collection<? extends Item>` means: *a collection of some **unknown** class which is or extends Item*. You can't add anything to such a collection, since you don't know the type of objects it holds.

Comment: If it _is_ or extends Item, why does it give an error if I try to add Item? I don't really understand why you can't add anything to such a collection.

Comment: Because you don't know its type. Replace Item by Vehicle. `Collection<? extends Vehicle>` could be `Collection<Vehicle>`, `Collection<Bicycle>` or `Collection<Car>`. You just don't know. And you can't add a `Car` to `Collection<Bicycle>`.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was interpreted as a Collection of anything that is a subtype of Vehicle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use T as template parameter?

```
public class ItemManager<T extends Item> {
    public static Collection<T> allItems;
    ...
    public static boolean addItem(T item){
        return allItems.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow Item and any subclass, you need to declare your collection with a lower bound:

```
public static Collection<? super Item> allItems;
```

This says "a collection of elements e where Item isSuperType(e) "

e.g.

```
public class Item {
}

public class SubItem extends Item {
}

public class OtherSubItem extends Item {
}

public static class ItemManager {
    public static Collection<? super Item> allItems;

    public static void addItems(){
        allItems.add(new Item());
        allItems.add(new SubItem());
        allItems.add(new OtherSubItem());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this require all elements to be the same subtype?

Comment: no, all it says is that the element contained by the collection have a lower bound of `Item` (some people read it easier as "element is Item or a subclass thereof" or "element is at least of type Item") - see code example.

Comment: I think this means any object that is a super-type of Item. "The syntax <? super T> denotes an unknown type that is a
supertype of T". Source: [Sun](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: I've always found that wording counter-intuitive when read on collections. The `? super T` denotes a lower-bound. It means that it's valid to assign `allItems = new Collection<Object>` as `Object` is a superclass of `Item`. But applied to the **elements** in the collection, it says that it allows 'any element that is at least of type T', creating a common baseline. In your case, Collection<? super Item> is equivalent to Collection<Item>, but if you were writing a generic class, Collection<? super T> would be the way to work with T and any subclass of T (like in your case)